# VBA Selection of filtered data

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I created a command button to pull data from a filtered list onto another sheet in the same workbook.  After clicking the button the first time, I wanted to set up the command to clear the landing page prior to populating it with refreshed data on subsequent clicks of the button.  The result was the following:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheets("Extract").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheets("Pricing Proposal").Select
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
Sheets("Extract").Select
Worksheets("Extract").Rows(6).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

The problem is that the clearing of the landing sheet is not always done when I click, leaving data on the landing sheet which is not wanted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add `Range(A:Z).Select` before clear contents

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed a simple "Cells.Select" which selects everything on the page, starting with cell A1. Not knowing how your page is set up, you might prefer selecting a specific range as commented below.

```
    Sheets("Extract").Select
    Cells.Select                        'or Range("A1:C6").Select or select Defined-Range like this Range(DefinedName).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Sheets("Pricing Proposal").Select
    Cells.Select                        ' or something like Range("A1:C8").Select or Range(DefinedName).Select or simpley Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Extract").Select
    Range("A1").Select                  ' or predefined Cell or range of cells or name as above comments
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A1").Select                  ' so the whole page isn't selected, or just pick a cell or delete this line if no need
```

Hope this helped out :)

Simplified: Your code with an addition

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheets("Extract").Select
Rows("1:6").Select
Selection.ClearContents
...
```